# Like application in django

Tags: django

I am looking for a generic 'like' application to use in a project am building in django. It's very similar to 'facebook like' where users can just click to 'like' or 'unlike' an object.

A generic app would be nice, kind of like the comments app that ships with django

Thanks

Comment: Have you browsed [Django packages](http://djangopackages.com/)?

Comment: @André Caron. Thanks for the link, found more stuff I can use in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [Django-voting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/)? It sounds like it would do what you need.