# Django Models for user, like, page like situation

Tags: django, schema, models

I have a model for users and another for page. Now I want to implemented something like Facebook's *like*. A user can like any page. Later I have to retrieve a list of all likes by a single user and also a list of all users who have liked a particular page.

I tried with making a separate model for Likes and making two fields as User (OneToOne) and Page(OnetoOne). But how would I get the data later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user = User.objects.get(username="foo")
user_likes = user.likes_set.all()

page = Page.objects.get(id=4)
page_likes = page.likes_set.all()
```

You can change the default name of the related manager in the definition of the fields in your Like model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="likes")
page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name="likes")
```

And you can then call them like:

```
user_likes = user.likes.all()
page_likes = page.likes.all()
```

As a side note, there are a few Django apps out there that could do that job:

- Django-Voting:
  [Like application in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318537/like-application-in-django)
- Phileo, under the Pinax project: https://github.com/eldarion/phileo